# How to make a search with separate views in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

How can I have an index page accept search input and then return the result in different page (view) with angularjs?

All the tutorials I have gone through on the internet shows search box that accepts the query and instantly prints results beneath it on the same page (or  say "view" in MVC language?). I want a separate page to just hold the search box, let user type what it wants and then hit go button which then return results on a separate page (which does not have the search box).

Comment: use a shared service between two controllers and assign your result into the service once you perform the search. Then do a redirect `$location.path('/second_view');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the search box value somewhere before going to the second page. You can do this in several ways.

---

One way would be to use a service to store the value, then the result page can retrieve it from there.

The service:

```
.service('CommonService', function(){
  this.value = '';
});
```

The search controller:

```
.controller('search', function(CommonService){
  $scope.goToResult = function(searchBoxValue){
    CommonService.value = searchBoxValue;
    // Redirect to result view
  };
});
```

This function could be on the `ng-submit` of the search form.

The result controller:

```
.controller('result', function(CommonService){
  // Receive value of search box
  $scope.receivedValue = CommonService.value;
});
```

---

Another way would be to send the value along the URL, like GET params:

```
http://google.com/q?SearchBoxValue=something-i-wrote-before
```

Answer (score 0):

are you implementing single page application (SPA)? you can do this multiple way with partial view and override partial view on search page with result page.

1. search page (partial) hit send request to get data.
2. receive data from service
3. redirect to result  (partial view).
4. you done.

hope this help you.